# The Crossroads of Dejection

Tags: logical-deduction, lateral-thinking, story

On all beings journey of life there will come a time in which an important decision must be made.

### This is that point in time

You have reached the *Crossroads of Dejection* as many lost travelers do, though no man who has sought it has found it.

[image: Crossroads of Direction]

With *50% chance of survival* the crossroads are the **epitome of evil**, with only the lucky or superiorly intelligent living to tell the tale...

Once there you can turn back or choose one of the three paths before you.

You look up and see the *Sign of Subdual* - and instantly faint.

Waking up you have forgotten the direction you came from, so turning back isn't an option. The Sign comes into focus...

[image: Sign of Subdual]

You see the four names of the paths, *Thade, Isedem, Afytse* and *Ertatre*<sup>*</sup>

You suddenly feel something in your hands and scramble up to find a scroll:

[image: Scroll]

On the back is a simple inscription:

[image: Inscription]

---

> ### Can you survive the Crossroads of Dejection?
>
> You'll have to work out which path to take...

*I made a typo, which is why sign says something else

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am not cent percent sure, but here is my answer.

We should go to

> Afytse.

**Reasoning:**

The names of the roads are

> anagrams: Thade=Death, Isedem=Demise, Afytse=Safety, Erratre=[Retraer](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/retraer)

Now,

> note the only the 'G' is bold in the grid, so it's where we should start, since "The Bold Survive".

Following the directions given on the margins, and the letters spell out

> GO TO SAFETY NOT TO DEATH OR DEMISE.

As a side note,

> It would make a bit more sense if Erratre were Ertatre instead, because it would be "Retreat" then. EDIT: As mentioned by the OP in the comments, it was a typo.

Comment: this is correct - it was supposed to be retreat obviously I made a typo

Comment: Oh, I guessed so :). It's amazing that it still evaluates to something nearly synonymous despite the typo. :0

Comment: Glad you could salvage it :)

Answer (score 4):

**Partial answer**

The scroll

> has N, E, S and W letters on above and below the grid. If you use them as four directions (North, East, South, West), starting from the middle you get
>  "Go to safety, not to death or demise"

Comment: Good start, need a bit more to complete the puzzle and a bit more explanation